# Compiling SQLite without doing the amalgamation

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm currently trying to add changes in how the SQLite virtual machine executes its code. To do that, I edit the `vdbe.c` file from the SQLite source.

The issue is, compiling SQLite consists in generating two huge implementation and header files (`sqlite3.c` and `sqlite3.h`) by amalgamating several smaller ones, after parsing some of them to generate code and documentation.

Unfortunately, the amalgamation process takes a relatively long time (about 15 seconds). I was wondering if there would be a somewhat easy way to not compile everything every time like it currently is the case, and possibly save a lot of compile time.

The main difficulty stems from the fact that source files are not valid by themselves (they can only compile once they have been amalgamated so that some types have already been defined earlier in the amalgamated file). After several attempts with a simple hand-written Python script (that would simply extract the virtual machine execution code from the amalgamation and keep the rest together), I came to the conclusion that there are two many edge cases to do it this way. I don't really know how to proceed.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: How are you building sqlite?

Comment: I got the source from the GitHub repository. So far, I've used the provided `Makefile` to do it (and I tried tinkering around but without any positive outcome)

Comment: You're fighting an uphill battle because the amalgamation is really how it's intended to be compiled. (And whatever GitHub repo you found is a mirror of the real repository which uses fossil, not git...)

Comment: The `configure` script in the `sqlite3-src-3XXXXXX.zip` source distribution has a `--disable-amalgamation` option that might be worth looking into.

Comment: @Shawn I know it is, but I can't bring myself to accept it

Comment: Also, I've found this parameter indeed and I'm experimenting with it at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in case anyone needs the answer in the future, here is how I did. You can find the whole discussion on [SQLite Forums](https://sqlite.org/forum/forumpost/f5168060db).

After getting the source:

- I have a first make pass where I don't change any file (to compile lemon, possibly among others):

```
make -f Makefile.linux-gcc
```

- Then, I edit `Makefile.linux-gcc` and replace all occurrences of `gcc` with `gcc -x none`
- I change `main.mk` and change the executable target by adding `-lstdc++` at the end:

```
sqlite3$(EXE):  shell.c libsqlite3.a sqlite3.h
    $(TCCX) $(READLINE_FLAGS) -o sqlite3$(EXE) $(SHELL_OPT) \
        shell.c libsqlite3.a $(LIBREADLINE) $(TLIBS) $(THREADLIB) -lstdc++
```

- I run make again using `make -f Makefile.linux-gcc` and get my sqlite3 executable as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: check in the amalgamation into your source code repository, treat it as your own artifact, and work on it. Whenever you wish to update the amalgamation, use git to help you.

1. Create two branches `sqlite-upstream` and `sqlite-local`.
2. Check in upstream amalgamation "v1" to `sqlite upstream`, then merge that to `sqlite-local` and do whatever local changes you need in that branch.
3. When upstream releases "v2", commit that to `sqlite-upstream`.
4. Merge or rebase - you may have some conflicts to resolve, but those will be much easier to deal with than manual change tracking.

   - Merge `sqlite-upstream` into `sqlite-local`, or
   - Duplicate `sqlite-local` into `sqlite-local-v2`, then rebase it onto `sqlite-upstream`, then use sqlite from that branch in dependent code.

Comment: That's what I initially wanted to do. Unfortunately, it's not realistic, given that the size of the amalgamated `sqlite3.c` is 8MB. Most IDEs refuse to do anything with files that large (and simply editing the file has terrible performance too)

Comment: Are you sure? I tried in current MSVC and Qt Creator (with legacy code model) and it works OK, I think?

Comment: Ah, lucky you. I did in CLion and it refuses to do anything when the file is more than 2,5MB approximately.

Comment: You can override these limits in CLion. You will definitely want to tweak the JVM settings though, or you'll run out of heap rather quickly. As for the platform to run it on: cache size and RAM latency matters much more than CPU speed for these workloads. A CPU with a big L3 cache but half the clock will run it much better than a speed demon with half the L3 cache. CLion - in my very limited experience - has a code model working set that usually just barely fits in L3. When it doesn't fit, things slow down a lot - direct RAM access is like swapfile thrashing, only faster :)

Comment: I agree though that the tweaking involved makes it far from good UX.

Comment: Thanks for these comments that are definitely insightful. I may come back to them one day. That said, the official SQLite forums have provided me with a solution that did exactly what I wanted to, so I'm going that way for now.

Comment: I'm glad :) Smaller files are definitely easier to work with. Part of the issue is that using code generators is not straightforward in major IDEs, unless they support cmake properly.